# How can someone prevent to become a victim of social engineering?

Tags: security-testing, security, penetration

There is a says that "There is no patch for human stupidity" Human is the weakest point of any system, In the field of Security "Social Engineering" is a very popular technique to gather information.

A lot of employees Knowingly or Unknowingly becoming the thread for organization So my question is How can someone prevent to be a victim of social engineering?

Comment: This question would be better asked in the information security stack exchange - although I would suggest searching there first, since it's probably already been asked and answered.

Comment: @KatePaulk this or any similar Question is not available on information security stack exchange I searched before asking. thanks

Comment: @nitinr - Your question still belongs to security exchange, not here. Show me the proof. Did you asked there? Show me the link. Show me your research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - it is related to security, not testing.

Comment: You could do worse than reading the answers to the questions listed here https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=social+engineering None ask your specific question, but many come close, particularly the ones about defending against social engineering.

Comment: Thanks @KatePaulk for the link it will help me to find my answer sorry I don't have much idea to use stack exchange I asked this question to penetration testing context. that's why I asked it here under security & penetration tag.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I think you are right stack exchange should close this question & remove all tags like security, penetration, security testing ...... Etc  from this group which help tester as per security point of view.... Right

Comment: @nitinr Why do you think we should remove "security" and "penetration" tags? You were confused and used them for wrong reason. It does not prevent others to use them for right reason, if they ask questions related to testing (your question was not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Continuous education is the key. Implement a strict security policy as well.**

Social engineering threat originates from both internal employees and external strangers.

**For Internal Employees:**

- In recent years, the most common factor in security breaching is **revenge**. People do not walk around with a revenge meter on the top of their heads, so there is no way to effectively identify people who are holding a grudge and about to breach security via social engineering.
- People who hold a grudge can look over others' shoulders for admin passwords, can sweet-talk to other colleagues into giving away confidential information and etc.
- Continuous education is the best defense you can get, although it is not a silver bullet.
- A company should establish its own security policy and educate its employees on regular intervals.
- Do not allow an employee to bring in their own laptops or take home work laptops if the project they are working on has a high sensitivity.
- Limit sensitive information to a need-to-know basis.

**For external strangers:**

- External strangers will have to "social engineer" internal employees into giving away information.
- Educate internal employees so that they are less likely to give away confidential information.
- Do not allow internal employees to take home any data storage hardware.

**Will it work?**

- To a degree, yes, but there is no bullet-proof in social engineering prevention.
- People will tell others secret voluntarily just to show off "I know something you do not."
- People will steal information for money, for revenge and etc.
- When a company grows beyond a certain size, you can not effectively control so many people or monitor them, at the end of the day, it all comes down to their willingness to keep a secret.